# error with predict function with lmer object

Tags: r, lme4

I'm trying to reproduce the plot from [Roland's code](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/99049/212831) with `lmer` instead of `nlme` model but I'm getting an error with the `predict` function:

```
library(nlme)
library(lme4)
library(ggplot2)

fm2 <- lmer(distance ~ age + Sex + (1|Subject), data = Orthodont)

newdat <- expand.grid(Sex=unique(Orthodont$Sex),
                  age=c(min(Orthodont$age),
                            max(Orthodont$age)))

p <- ggplot(Orthodont, aes(x=age, y=distance, colour=Sex)) +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  geom_line(aes(y=predict(fm2), group=Subject, size="Subjects")) +
  geom_line(data=newdat, aes(y=predict(fm2, level=0, newdata=newdat), size="Population")) +
  scale_size_manual(name="Predictions", values=c("Subjects"=0.5, "Population"=3)) +
  theme_bw(base_size=22)
```

This is the error I get:

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Subject' not found
In addition: Warning message:
In predict.merMod(fm2, level = 0, newdata = newdat) :
  unused arguments ignored
```

Comment: You used the `Subject` variable to fit your model. But your new data doesn't have a `Subject` variable so you can't make a prediction using that data.

Comment: Seems related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/262277/why-would-you-predict-from-a-mixed-effect-model-without-including-random-effects. Try using `predict(fm2, newdata=newdat, re.form=~0)` to ignore the Subject effect for new values (assuming that's how you want to handle prediction)

Comment: Thank you @MrFlick that was it. Do you see any issues using `re.form=0` in the example? Or is it safe to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to plot subject-level predictions, you would need to include `Subject` in your prediction frame:

```r
pframe <- with(Orthodont,
  expand.grid(Sex=unique($Sex),
              age=range(age),
              Subject=unique(Subject))
)
```

Alternately you could include `re.form = ~0` in your `predict` call: this is equivalent to the (ignored!) `level=0` specification in your current code, which only works for `lme` ...